# "Click" não funciona no angular

Tags: angular

Segue os códigos. Apesar de esconder o menu, ele não volta a abrir com a função "click" no nav-burger

menu.component:

```
section class="hero outer is-primary is-fullheight animated slideInLeft" [ngClass]="{'is-hidden' : !menu.opened}">
```

menu.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class MenuService {
  opened: boolean;

  constructor() { }
  open (){
    this.opened = true;
  }

}
```

header.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  providers: [MenuService],
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.sass']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public menu:MenuService) {
```

header html:

```
 <div class="navbar-burger burger" (click)="menu.open()">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Voce tem que ter a funcao no component

header.component.ts

```
@Component({
  providers: [MenuService],
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.sass']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public menu:MenuService) { }

 openMenu(){
   this.menu.open()
  }
}
```

E no html:

```
 <div class="navbar-burger burger" (click)="openMenu()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso, você ira ter que usar  @Output()

```js
      @Output() menu = new EventEmitter()


  emitAddEvent(){
    this.menu.emit(this.menuItem)
  }
```